# jquery selection in variable doesnt work in .index() method

Tags: jquery, variables, indexing

Expected result is to get red all special divs between first and last selected div.

This works but couldnt be it better written?:

```
var s = $('div.selected'),
    $spec = $('.speial'),
    i = s.first().index('.speial'),
    last = s.last().index('.speial');
for(;i<last;i++){
  $spec.eq(i).addClass('gored');
}
```

I was trying this:

```
var s = $('div.selected'),
    $spec = $('.speial'),
    i = s.first().index($spec),
    last = s.last().index($spec);
for(;i<last;i++){
  $spec.eq(i).addClass('gored');
}
```

But it doesnt work... I am interested in the reason why.
Or maybe is there even better way to achieve the same result?

EDIT: I have made the fiddle to get picture of the problem :) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luckylooke/dbrAY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery API doc:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
>   element is not found, .index() will return -1.

So It seems I have firstly misunderstood the relativity in both cases, so I thought that "elements matched by the selector" could be replaced by selection (jQuery object).

The answer is that .index() works another way than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want without seeing the HTML

Please clarify if I have got this wrong but it seems as if you want to add the class `gored` to all `.speial` within `div.selected`;

In which case this is easier:

```
$('div.selected .speial').addClass("gored");
```

As I said this might be wrong, please feel free to clarify exactly what you want in plain english (preferably with HTML snippet)

Comment: I could only understand the question after reading your answer and it makes sense now. +1

Comment: In HTML there is complex structure of div and other tags which are dynamically changed, but I can clarify that ONLY .speial could be also .selected. So .selected are selection from .speial. My aim is to .gored all .speial between first and last .speial.selected divs. I hope you understand me now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS :first-child and :last-child selectors

Comment: $('div.selected:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').addClass("gored"); this worked for me!

Comment: .selected are selection from .speial. My aim is to .gored all .speial between first and last .speial.selected divs. I hope you understand me now :)

Comment: Exactly to .gored all .speial(WITHOUT .selected) between first and last .speial.selected ?

Comment: No. :/ To .gored all .speial(WITH or WITHOUT .selected, doesnt matter) between first and last of .speial.selected, where first and last are not included. .speial.selected can be more than two, but interesting are first and last in dom order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('div.selected:not(:first):not(:last)').addClass('gored');
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ5h/)

Comment: .selected are selection from .speial. My aim is to .gored all .speial between first and last .speial.selected divs. I hope you understand me now :)

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle? How would you want it changed?

Comment: Can you modify your fiddle and hard code in it how the final result should look like? It's hard to grasp what you're trying to do.

Comment: Final result in my fiddle is as I wanted. I was writing here because I wanted to use .index() with variable, like this .index($spec) to code become faster, but it doesnt work.